# IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Tags: python, file-io, ioerror

I have a sort of xml like file here: https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/data/semcor3.0_naf/brown1/br-e24.naf

And when I tried to read it as below, I got an `IOError`:

```
>>> import io
>>> infile = io.open('pywsd/data/semcor3.0_naf/brown1/br-e24.naf', 'r', encoding='utf8')
>>> infile.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

**What does `IOError: [Errono5]` mean?**

**Has the error tell me that something is wrong in how I read the file or something wrong with the file?**

**How do I resolve the error?**

Comment: Most likely because I see a few google results with the same question. (Not downvoting, but considering it)

Comment: but not answer to this problem. I've tried googling too.

Comment: Unfortunately this question falls under the "why isn't my code working" category, so that also might be why. Try improving your question with what you've done to debug, links to questions you've cited, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man errno` says errno 5 is `EIO`: `Input/output error (POSIX.1)`.

Pretty generic and the same you get in your exception.

This is as far as this can be explored from the information provided.

Comment: I've tried it on another machine and it seems to be a hardware problem. It was fine on another machine =(

Comment: You can double check reading the file with something else like `cat`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem at university when I exceeded my quota.

You can check your quota with

```
quota -s
```