# Python: os.listdir OSError [Errno 5] Input/output error: 'tmp/json_folder'

Tags: python, bash, docker, operating-system, oserror

**Problem:**

I have one folder(**json_folder_large**) which holds more than 200, 000 json files inside, another folder(**json_folder_small**)  which holds 10, 000 json files inside.

```
import os
lst_file = os.listdir("tmp/json_folder_large") # this returns an OSError
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: 'tmp/json_folder_large'
```

I got an **OSError** when I use listdir with directory path. I am sure there is no problem with the path because I can do the same thing with the other folder without this OSError.

```
lst_file = os.listdir("tmp/json_folder_small") # no error with this
```

**Env:**

Problem above is with **docker image as pycharm interpreter**.

When the interpreter is **conda env**, **there is no errors**.

The only difference here I could see is that in my docker/preferences/resources/advanced, I set 4 CPU(max is 6) and 32GB memory(max is 64).

**I tried:(under docker)**

**1. With Pathlib**

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path('tmp/json_folder_large').iterdir() # this returns a generator <generator object Path.iterdir at 0x7fae4df499a8>
for x in pathlib.Path('tmp/json_folder_large').iterdir():
    print("hi")
    break

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1074, in iterdir for name in self._accessor.listdir(self):
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: 'tmp/json_folder_large'
```

**2. With os.scandir**

```
os.scandir("tmp/json_folder_large") # this returns a generator <posix.ScandirIterator object at 0x7fae4c48f510>
for x in os.scandir("tmp/json_folder_large"):
    print("hi")
    break
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: 'tmp/json_folder_large'
```

**3.Connect pycharm terminal to docker container, then do `ls`**

```
docker exec -it 21aa095da3b0 bash
cd json_folder_large
ls
```

Then I **got an error**(when the terminal is **not connected to docker container**, the code above **raise no error!!!!!**)

```
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it really because of the memory issue?
2. Is it possible to **solve this error** while everything is under **the same directory**? (I see we could split those files into different directories)
3. Why my code **raise error under docker but not conda env**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm. Did you try ```os.listdir("/tmp/json_folder_large")?```

Comment: Hi, @mutantkeyboard, I am sure the path should be 'tmp/json_folder_large', if I do `os.listdir("/tmp/json_folder_large")`, I will get a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/json_folder_large'`. By the way my current working directory is `'/opt/project'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOError: \[Errno 5\] Input/output error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805025/ioerror-errno-5-input-output-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os.scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) or [glob.iglob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob). They make use of iterator and avoid loading the entire list in memory.

Comment: I just tried with `os.scandir` and `Path` from pathlib, nothing works in my case, I will update this into my question

Comment: You mean you get the i/o error when using os.scandir also?

Comment: Hi @lllrnr101 I updated the part with os.scandir, the moment I iterate through the generator it raise an error

Comment: Then I think memory is not your problem. I would put a sleep(60) and then attach the process to strace and see if I get any clue.

Comment: Do the calls for scnadir or listdir with a pattern also give you error. Like trying to get only a suibset of files from that dir?

Comment: I didn't add any pattern, anyway if it is cased by those reasons, then I could not explain why it works under **conda environment**, the only case it raise this error it's under **docker**