# how to fixc Input/Output Error when opening image file

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, shutil

Currently learning reading image by csv and crop it with the data in the csv and i got I/O Error at my data image

the csv has data like below

```
filename    width   height  class   xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax
Data16_173_55.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  476.25  100.14815   518.125 148.03148
Data16_173_56.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  474.68753   95.14074    517.1875    153.0389
Data16_173_57.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  468.125 93.26296    518.125 149.5963
Data16_173_58.jpg   600 338 Membuka Smartphone  470.3125    101.08704   519.0625    148.34444
```

and i am currently trying to crop it and replace the image using looping code by reading the filename, here's the **code**

```
import shutil
import os
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')
for index, row in data.iterrows():
  input_name  = os.path.join("imagesXRP", row["filename"])
  xmin  = row["xmin"]
  ymin = row['ymin']
  xmax  = row["xmax"]
  ymax = row['ymax']
  im = Image.open(input_name)
  im1 = im.crop((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
  im1.save(input_name)
```

any answer would be help

thank you so much !

`OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: 'imagesXRP/Data16_173_55.jpg'`

Comment: Does the directory/folder `imagesXRP` exist and already placed in the same folder as your python file?

Comment: Yes it is exist and placed in the same folder

Comment: Probably error on the disk itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805025/ioerror-errno-5-input-output-error . Have you tried on another device such as VM or even Google Colab/Kaggle Notebook?

Comment: i run this code on collab

Comment: What about using `./imagesXRP` instead of `imagesXRP` in the `os.path.join`?

Comment: nope, still have the same error

Comment: Have you tried checking with `os.path.exists()` for the folder `imagesXRP` and all the images?

Comment: i did and got no error for it